# Where does parameter in call back function come from? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, eventemitter

For example, `chat` is an EventEmitter. The call back function can accept a param called `message`. My question is where does the `message` come from? Does the event `message` provide it? If it is so, could you guys please give me a sample of the event `message` and let me see when it is triggered, how the param was provided to the `chat` EventEmitter? Thank you guys very much.

```
chat.on('message',function(message){
    console.log(message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `message` parameter comes from whatever triggered the event.

You can see from the [source](https://github.com/tmpvar/node-eventemitter/blob/master/index.js) of `EventEmitter` that `on` is a synonym for `addListener`:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.on = EventEmitter.prototype.addListener;
```

And then you can see that `addListener` just puts the handler in a list of all handlers of the provided type (simplified code):

```
EventEmitter.prototype.addListener = function(type, listener) {
  // ...  
  if (!this._events) this._events = {};
  // ...
  this._events[type] = this._events[type] || [];
  this._events[type].push(listener);
  // ...
  return this;
};
```

Then `emit` calls every handler in the appropriate list:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function(type) {
  // ...
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  var listeners = this._events[type];
  for (var i = 0, l = listeners.length; i < l; i++) {
    listeners[i].apply(this, args);
  }
  return true;
  // ...
```

};

So that when you say `.emit('message', "Hello")`, `args` will be `["Hello"]`, and `listeners[i].apply(this, args)` will send this list of arguments to `function(message) { /* ... */ }` that you defined in your `.on` call: this is how `message` becomes `"Hello"`.